# Different discounting methods with SRILM toolikt

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora, discourse-analysis, language-models

I want to do some smoothing on a corpus and compare the results.
for train language model without smoothing I used "-addsmooth 0" option
now I should add two different smoothing and compare them, I couldn't find any command for "Good Turing" and "Kneser-Ney" Smoothing .
I found somewhere this command :

```
ngram-count - vocab Lexicon2003-72k.txt
-read CNA0001-2M.count
-order 3
-lm CNA0001-2M_N3_KN.lm
-kndiscount1
-kndiscount2
-kndiscount3
```

but it is modified kneser-ney and I cant understand what is different between `-kndiscount1` and `-kndiscount2` for example. what is the meaning of that number?(1,2)
and why we should used them together?

I don't want to use interpolation.

Comment: This is about programming and there doesn't seem to be any linguistic content.

Comment: @user6726 computational linguistics is on-topic here.

Comment: In answer to the first part, I don't think SRILM offers Good-Turing smoothing. I think it just offers KN and modifications of KN

Answer (score 1):

GT is SRILM's default. In fact, I think using -addsmooth 0 just gives you default GT smoothing (unfortunately?). To directly use GT discounting, simply include no discounting argument.

The number at the end of the discount argument (-kndiscount1, etc.) is the n-gram order to apply that discounting method to. Using -kndiscount alone tells ngram-count to use it for all orders.

Review the manual for more on this command: (speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/ngram-count.1.html)